# How to add temperature tab to task manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, temperature, task-manager

I know that almost all processors nowadays have built in temperature sensors.  How and why aren't these part of task manager (or the performance tab)?

Is there a way to add a temperature tab, or another way to view this information in a similar way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [HardWare Monitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html):

> HWMonitor is a hardware monitoring program that reads PC systems main
>   health sensors : voltages, temperatures, fans speed. The program
>   handles the most common sensor chips, like ITE® IT87 series, most
>   Winbond® ICs, and others. In addition, it can read modern CPUs on-die
>   core thermal sensors, as well has hard drives temperature via
>   S.M.A.R.T, and video card GPU temperature.

If you wish to see only the CPU temperature, and are not concerned about anything else, [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) is a more compact, smaller foot print program:

> The uniqueness of it is that it shows the temperature of each
>   individual core in each processor in your system! You can see in real
>   time how the CPU temperature varies when you load your CPU. It's also
>   completely motherboard independent.

Comment: Thanks, why doesn't windows include it in task manager, or performance manager...?

Comment: Doing so would require Microsoft to support all of the myriad different configurations of temperature sensors in every processor capable of running Windows, not to mention future processors.  Remember, Windows doesn't support _only_ "modern processors", but ancient ones as well, and those that don't yet exist.  If people had to download windows updates to the task manager every other day just to support this feature, there would be hell to pay.  Coretemp is updated all the time to support new processors, but it isn't reasonable to expect that from a core component of Windows.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be so much simpler to have a driver, (and contained in the driver is the temp sensor), or have Microsoft identify your hardware, then download yours once.  It could be an optional update, that users could install in their first Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an Windows 7 post but it was a top result in my Windows 10 Google search, so I thought you might like to know this:

Windows 10 is going to show GPU temperature.  "This will be part of Windows 10’s 20H1 update, which will become stable sometime around May 2020"

https://www.howtogeek.com/437378/windows-10-will-show-gpu-temperature-in-the-task-manager/

Answer (score 1):

I use Piriform's Speccy - Gives all temperatures, seems to have sensible built in warning levels. It was the first time I knew my external 640GB USB drive was overheating.
https://www.piriform.com/speccy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Argus Monitor](https://www.argusmonitor.com/en/index.php). It's a hardware temperature monitoring tool. It measures CPU, Hard Disk and GPU Temperature and also monitors the Hard Disk using  S.M.A.R.T and displays processor fan speed.

This software allows the user to mark the threshold value for the hardware's temperature. You can select the task to perform when the threshold value is reached.